# Keras MaxPooling2D layer does not reduce the shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am building a neural network, more specifically a CNN to classify the locations of various proteins in human cell organelles. I have 512 x 512 images in 4 channels R, G, B, and Y:

```
def ModelMaker(intTuple):

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(8, (7, 7), strides=(2, 2), kernel_initializer='he_normal', bias_initializer='zeros',
                     kernel_regularizer='l2', padding='valid', data_format="channels_last", input_shape=intTuple))

    model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', kernel_regularizer='l2'))
    model.add(PReLU(alpha_initializer=VarianceScaling(scale=1.0, mode='fan_in', distribution='normal', seed=None)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))

    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', kernel_regularizer='l2'))
    model.add(PReLU(alpha_initializer=VarianceScaling(scale=1.0, mode='fan_in', distribution='normal', seed=None)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', kernel_regularizer='l2'))
    model.add(PReLU(alpha_initializer=VarianceScaling(scale=1.0, mode='fan_in', distribution='normal', seed=None)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))

    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', kernel_regularizer='l2'))
    model.add(PReLU(alpha_initializer=VarianceScaling(scale=1.0, mode='fan_in', distribution='normal', seed=None)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))

    model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', kernel_regularizer='l2'))
    model.add(PReLU(alpha_initializer=VarianceScaling(scale=1.0, mode='fan_in', distribution='normal', seed=None)))
    model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))

    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(28))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    return model

model = ModelMaker((512, 512, 4))
model.summary()
```

Everything is good, but when I create a model and run a `model.summary()`, and go through the layers, something is wierd. I have the following sequence of layers for each convolution: `Conv2D ---> PReLU ---> MaxPooling2D/AveragePooling2D`. However, the model summary looks like this:

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 253, 253, 8)       1576      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 253, 253, 16)      1168      
_________________________________________________________________
p_re_lu_5 (PReLU)            (None, 253, 253, 16)      1024144   
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 253, 253, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 253, 253, 32)      4640      
_________________________________________________________________
p_re_lu_6 (PReLU)            (None, 253, 253, 32)      2048288   
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling2 (None, 253, 253, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 253, 253, 64)      18496     
_________________________________________________________________
p_re_lu_7 (PReLU)            (None, 253, 253, 64)      4096576   
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_6 (MaxPooling2 (None, 253, 253, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)           (None, 253, 253, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
p_re_lu_8 (PReLU)            (None, 253, 253, 128)     8193152   
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_7 (MaxPooling2 (None, 253, 253, 128)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)           (None, 253, 253, 256)     295168    
_________________________________________________________________
p_re_lu_9 (PReLU)            (None, 253, 253, 256)     16386304  
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling2d_1 (Average (None, 253, 253, 256)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 16386304)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 28)                458816540 
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 28)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 490,959,908
Trainable params: 490,959,908
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Something seems to be wrong with the dimensionality reduction. The size of the tensors is all the same for the first two dimensions (253, 253, XX). It stays constant at 253... only the channel sizes increase, which is normal. I removed my last two dense layer stacks as the model won't even define itself as the runtime crashes as the ram is used up. I am guessing this is due to the MONSTROUS size of the dense layers when the shape (253, 253, 256) is flattened and passed. The entire model won't fit on the RAM. Help!

Comment: Why not post a more minimal model that shows the problem?

Comment: The combination of `strides=(1,1)` and `padding='same'` is responsible for keeping your sizing identical across your conv2d layers. What do you expect the layer shapes to be?

Comment: I expect the layer shapes to decrease from 256 --> 128 --> 64 --> 32 --> 16 etc, the size should go down, right? If I remove padding from my MaxPooling2D layers, I get a shape error, but the strides = (2, 2) fixes the issue as answered by @Nicolas Gervais.

Comment: Well think about it. With `strides=(2,2)` you're sliding your convolutional window two units each time it moves in the x and y directions, which will of course produce an output that's half the width and height of the input...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strides=(2, 2)` or leave them blank. Then, the `max_pooling2d` will work. The number of trainable parameters will decrease significantly. If unspecified, `max_pooling2d` will default to `pool_size`. See the [docs](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot that I had the stride parameter set to (1, 1), what does it normally default to? Setting strides = (2, 2) fixes the problem right up! The number of trainable parameters went down too.